# Changed washer in shower and now it squeaks at low volume

Tags: plumbing, shower, washer

I changed a standard rubber washer on the cold water in my 50 year old shower and now the cold water makes a steady, high pitch, squeaking noise at low volume.  The squeak changes pitch as I turn the water on more (but I do not need that much cold water.).  What might I have done wrong and how do I fix the noise?

Update: It is now several weeks later and the cold water no longer squeaks. (It healed itself.). Why?

Comment: Did you use the right size washer and tighten it in good?

Comment: Is it a form of water hammer?  Or just like water through a restriction? Turn it off tightly a few times and see if deforming the seat helps. I doubt you did anything wrong it’s the conical geometry of the washer and a narrow opening causing the noise.

Comment: @EdBeal It is a high pitch squeak. I edited the question to give more detail.

Comment: @JACK I put in a flat washer that seemed to be the right size.  I thought I tightened it pretty well.  Certainly not left loose.  Should I redo it with a different washer?